# Move out Typescript declarations to separate file?

Tags: typescript

My file that contains both declarations and other code has become too long. Here is a part of my `./src/index.ts` file:

```
// --> I want to move this to a separate file 
export interface Client extends Options {
    transactionsCounter: number;
    requestCallbacks: any;
    socket: any;
}
// <-- I want to move this to a separate file

export class Client {
    constructor(options: Options) {
        const defaultOptions = { 
            host: 'ws://127.0.0.1',
            port:  8080,
            logger: function() {
                const prefix = "LOG:";
                console.log.call(null, prefix, ...Array.from(arguments))
            },
            maxTime: 30000, 
            startFromTransactionId: 1
        };

        Object.assign(this, { ...defaultOptions, ...options });

        this.transactionsCounter = 0;
        this.requestCallbacks = {};
        this.socket = null; 
    }
}
```

What is a good way to move out TypeScript declarations to a separate file?

Do I just put it in a separate file and use imports for every declaration or is there some magic that allows me to move the declarations to another file but still have them in the namespace of my code?

Comment: Bad idea giving an interface and a class the same name. I'd prefix all the interfaces with "I", so that your case will become "IClient". Same thing for "Options" => "IOptions".

Comment: By the way, did you forget to add "implements IClient" to the class, maybe?

Comment: @MarioVernari His code compiles precisely because the interface and the class have the same name. ;)

Comment: @MarioVernari: thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I just put it in a separate file and use imports for every declaration

Yep.

Notice that the IDE can help you by automatically writing imports.